# Fetch Data from on premise Database, SAP HANA Cloud for SPFx adaptive card Extension

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extension

I am trying to achieve. looking for how to retrieve and store data on a database system deployed on-premise, such as an **SAP HANA solution** that has its own database through the custom **Viva Connections ACE(Adaptive Card Extension)**  card which I am trying to create. To give you an idea an example a customer has a locally deployed payroll Management solution that uses a local database.

I am trying to connect the ACE card to that database to display the payroll information for an Employee in the card which will be added to the Viva connections Dashboard inside Microsoft Teams.

Answer (score 1):

Develop the SPFx Adaptive Card Extension that will be displayed within SharePoint.
In the Adaptive Card Extension, use the HttpClient provided by SPFx to make a request to your backend Web API. This request should trigger the data retrieval from the SAP HANA Cloud database.